# Custom Webservice for wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I need to extend org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub to contain an additional method which allows me to obtain the AD attributes of other users.

Is it possible to create a custom webservice for Identity Server 4.5. We are not using any other wso2 products. Wso2 IS only will ship with the solution distribution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate API for user management functions which is called as "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" service. This service exposes all user management function as a web service.... "UserAdmin" is also user management web service that has been implemented specially for WSO2 Carbon UI.

You have methods in the "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" to retrieve AD attributes (user attributes)

Please find the java client from [here](https://github.com/soasecurity/soasecurity/tree/master/user-mgt/client/remote-user-400). There is a readme file also there